# Dropdown menu options rendering outside of dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm customizing a WordPress theme and right now I'm trying to include a series of conditional dropdowns that allow users to select their Country, State, and City. The following html code works fine in your average online simulator, but when I use it in my WordPress theme, the options in the second dropdown menu render outside of the dropdown menu.

Here is the code:

```
<select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
<select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="[script]"></script>
```

[Here is a screenshot of how it appears with dev tools open on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xdFh.png)

and

[here is a screenshot of how it appears with dev tools open on an html simulator site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6rkp.png)

As you can see, the country dropdown menu renders fine but the state dropdown menu has its options loaded into the wrong section! I can't even select a state, so I can't say what the cities dropdown menu looks like.

What could be going on here?

### Edit 1

I know you're not supposed to do script tags in html for WordPress sites, but I don't think that's what's causing the problem. I'll get around to doing this all better when I'm less of a beginner.

### Edit 2

Okay, so it seems like the problem is stemming from some incompatibility with the bootstrap-select.min JS and CSS files. I'm using the latest versions of both. Any idea what I could change in these to make it so my data funnels into the correct html elements?

Comment: Hi Greg, you need to include all of the relevant code to reproduce your error.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for responding! Unfortunately I don't even know what the relevant code is. There are tons of theme files that are proprietary. I'm more looking for a general idea of what could be causing this, and where I could go to begin addressing it. I have also contacted the theme developer but figured I'd post here too.

Comment: You don't use the classes of select, so no style

Answer (score 0):

1. class="countries"
2. class="states"
3. class="cities"

This three classes are not defined, you have to look int your file and check .css files where this classes are defined, than you can try it. You don't have any kind of style, just html in this case.

I make you an example how you can use css and html.

Only **HTML**

```html
<h1>Hi, let's learn it</h1>
```

But  just by adding a class,or just style `h1` it will be this

**HTML + CSS**

```css
h1{
  text-align:center;
  background:#dfdfdf;
  margin:auto;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:72px;
  font-family:'Verdana';
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi, let's learn it</h1>
```

And more, add a jQuery, this

**HTML + CSS + JQUERY**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('h1').mousemove(function(e){
     var rXP = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft-$(this).width()/2);
     var rYP = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop-$(this).height()/2);
     $('h1').css('text-shadow', +rYP/10+'px '+rXP/80+'px rgba(227,6,19,.8), '+rYP/8+'px '+rXP/60+'px rgba(255,237,0,1), '+rXP/70+'px '+rYP/12+'px rgba(0,159,227,.7)');
   });
});
```

```css
h1{
   text-align:center;
  background:#dfdfdf;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:72px;
  font-family:'Verdana';
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hi, let's learn it</h1>
```

I hope you understend the concept

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, my problem isn't that these have no style--it's that the options in the state dropdown menu are for some reason rendered outside of the dropdown section when the html is generated

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the problem was: bootstrap-select.min.js was percolating my `countries`, `states`, and `cities` class tags up to the first inserted html element, meaning the results my own script spit out were being duplicated in the `<div>` and `<select>` elements. I took care of this by targeting element id tags instead of class tags by using `$('#id')` instead of `$('.class')` in my main JavaScript file. That took care of the "spilled" menu contents. Next, I had to figure out why the `<select>` options weren't being converted into `<li>` by bootstrap. The solution, though it took a while to find, was quite simple. I simply had to refresh the contents of the dropdown menu. I did this by adding the `$('#id').selectpicker('refresh');` code after any instance where new options were propagated. Hope someone can find some use from this in the future!